# NiFi, Authentication and Authorization using LDAP in windows 10

Tags: docker, ldap, apache-nifi

I want to setup authentication for Nifi in Windows 10.

I used an OpenLDAP docker container. To start a LDAP server, execute command below:

`docker run --name my-openldap -p 389:389 -p 636:636 -d osixia/openldap`

Then LDAP server is accessible using docker machine ip. Next, I configured `nifi.properties` file in the `config` folder inside nifi server binary files and updated the following line:

`nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=ldap-provider`

Then, I updated the following line in `login-identity-providers.xml` inside `conf` folder:

```
  <provider>
    <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
    <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>
    <property name="Manager DN">cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org</property>
    <property name="Manager Password">admin</property>
    <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Url">ldap://192.168.99.100</property>
    <property name="User Search Base">dc=example,dc=org</property>
    <property name="User Search Filter">cn={0}</property>
    <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
  </provider>
```

After, I restarted NiFi, it automatically gets stopped. These are some errors from logs file.

```
2021-08-07 18:08:04,120 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2021-08-07 18:08:04,138 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@8909c3{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:8443}
2021-08-07 18:08:04,138 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session node0 Stopped scavenging
```

Need some help.

edits:

```
2021-08-07 22:59:45,462 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=222ms
2021-08-07 22:59:45,501 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.C._nifi_content_viewer No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2021-08-07 22:59:45,510 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ace0b1{nifi-content-viewer,/nifi-content-viewer,file:///C:/Users/Singh's/Downloads/nifi-1.14.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.14.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{.\work\nar\extensions\nifi-server-nar-1.14.0.nar-unpacked\NAR-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-content-viewer-1.14.0.war}
2021-08-07 22:59:45,714 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=22ms
2021-08-07 22:59:45,718 WARN [main] o.e.j.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor Duplicate mapping from / to default
2021-08-07 22:59:45,719 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler._nifi_docs No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2021-08-07 22:59:45,762 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4e5dee{nifi-docs,/nifi-docs,file:///C:/Users/Singh's/Downloads/nifi-1.14.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.14.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{.\work\nar\extensions\nifi-server-nar-1.14.0.nar-unpacked\NAR-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-docs-1.14.0.war}
2021-08-07 22:59:45,897 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=20ms
2021-08-07 22:59:45,901 INFO [main] o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler._ No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2021-08-07 22:59:45,939 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@11f1eaf{nifi-error,/,file:///C:/Users/Singh's/Downloads/nifi-1.14.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.14.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{.\work\nar\extensions\nifi-server-nar-1.14.0.nar-unpacked\NAR-INF\bundled-dependencies\nifi-web-error-1.14.0.war}
2021-08-07 22:59:48,673 INFO [main] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@8909c3{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:8443}
2021-08-07 22:59:48,674 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @183684ms
2021-08-07 22:59:48,676 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAnonymousAuthenticationProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authorizer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1129)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:159)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:303)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAnonymousAuthenticationProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authorizer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAnonymousAuthenticationProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authorizer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:139)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:55)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:387)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:166)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authorizer' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizer': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.authorization.AuthorizerFactoryBean.performMethodInjection(AuthorizerFactoryBean.java:413)
    at org.apache.nifi.authorization.AuthorizerFactoryBean.createAuthorizer(AuthorizerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.apache.nifi.authorization.AuthorizerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthorizerFactoryBean.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169)
    ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: SingleUserAuthorizer requires org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.SingleUserLoginIdentityProvider to be configured
    at org.apache.nifi.authorization.single.user.SingleUserAuthorizer.setProperties(SingleUserAuthorizer.java:69)
    ... 112 common frames omitted
2021-08-07 22:59:48,706 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2021-08-07 22:59:48,718 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@8909c3{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:8443}
2021-08-07 22:59:48,718 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session node0 Stopped scavenging
```

Comment: Those aren't errors, it's just shutdown info. Is there an actual error or stacktrace in the logs? Can you `telnet 192.168.99.100 389` and successfully connect?

Comment: @Sdairs I have edited the post and added the errors from log file. Please help. I am not able to start the server.

Comment: This is the important one `Caused by: org.apache.nifi.authorization.exception.AuthorizerCreationException: SingleUserAuthorizer requires org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.SingleUserLoginIdentityProvider to be configured` You have `SingleUserAuthorizer` still configured somewhere, check your authorizers.xml